# Configuring Sonic wall tz 500 LAN interface with a internal dns and dhcp

Tags: dhcp, sonicwall, wide-area-network, dns-zone, wlan

I trying to configuring a sonicwall tz500. I have a internal AD server with DHCP and DNS for the domain. 10.0.0.5 is the address of dhcp and DNS. question is on the LAN 0X interface, do I assign it a static IP in the domain range? Also what would the gateway be? I want the traffic to flow out to WAN. Is there something I need to add in the DHCP? The WAN is connected to a internet through DSL modem and receives a IP and everything fine. When I currently connect, the PC's in the domain still can talk to each other and print. Thank you for your help in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do the same as you will do on a Linksys, except the interface is not the same.

> do I assign it a static IP in the domain range?

Yes. Same range as your LAN. aka 10.0.0.x

> Also what would the gateway be?

Nothing, you **are** the gateway of your LAN.

> Is there something I need to add in the DHCP?

Give the router IP to be the gateway for computer in the LAN.

Comment: okay, so give the ip in the LAN, but the LAN currently has a active directory domain with 15 pcs and few printers, that receive there ips from the dhcp and dns server on the domain controller. There is a 24 port switch that has all the devices plugged into. I understand that the LAN ip assigned to that port is the gateway. But how does the domain know what the gateway is? don't I have to add something into the dhcp on the DC to redirect the traffic to the gateway? oh and thank you for the response.

Comment: @sunnys in the dhcp you give the gateway ip, so all client will know it after

Comment: Okay got it, thanks for your help! defined it in the dhcp scope to point to the assigned ip by me. Also placed a reservation, don't know if it needed it. The current gateway defined in the scope is 10.0.0.254, would it have made since that I assign that ip to the LAN port?

Comment: @sunnys HI, yes, a reservation does not hurt. Just be sure nothing else got that ip in big. (the reservation help as it would never give that ip to another computer)